# How do I pass an HTML element to a higher-order function (HOC) in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, higher-order-components

I often use [HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to provide additional functionality to an existing React component, which is pretty straightforward:

```js
import Component from '/path/to/Component';
import higherOrderComponent from '/path/to/higherOrderComponent';

const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(Component);
```

However, I need to wrap a simple HTML `input`, which doesn't exist as a standalone React component. I tried

```js
const EnhancedInput = higherOrderComponent(<input />);
```

and got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

How can I properly pass the input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the string name of the HTML element you want to wrap:

```js
const EnhancedInput = higherOrderComponent('input');
```

The error clued me into what I needed to do and made more sense when breaking down what JSX is doing. `<input />` is simply [JSX syntactic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements) for `React.createElement('input')`.

If the HOC looks something like this:

```
const higherOrderComponent = (Component) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Component {...} />
      );
    }
  }
};
```

then the `render` method is ultimately returning

```
React.createElement(Component, {...});
```

Therefore, passing the string `'input'` to the HOC means it will return `React.createElement('input', {...});`, which is the same as `<input />` as asserted above.

Comment: This doesn't allow child nodes to be inserted without adding extra functionality to your HOC function. Consider user2542281's solution below as an alternative.

Comment: @Artif3x sure it does. I think you may be misunderstanding how HOCs are applied and used. You should be passing a component function or class, not an instance. Once the HOC is applied, you can instantiate the enhanced component and pass whatever children you want. See https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html for more.

Comment: As I understand your answer, you are proposing to use only a single string as the parameter for the higherOrderComponent function, where I believe the original question, from the code example included, was how to use JSX as the parameter. Your example certainly works for a single HTML tag, but there's no way to use your string example and still include child nodes, as JSX would easily allow.
You could add more parameters to your HOC function, but that seems a much more complex and difficult to read solution than simply wrapping the JSX in an arrow function.

Comment: Again, I think you're misunderstanding how HOCs are used. Passing children is unrelated to the original question, since that would typically be done using the "enhanced" component. Here's an example of what I believe you're asking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmggyg?editors=0010

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use a function that returns the HTML you want.

`const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(()=><input />)`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted one above doesn't allow for child nodes within the input tag.

Comment: @Artif3x you may still explicitly specify children property in the props parameter in React.createElement