# Getting the following error when creating React HOC: type is invalid -- expected string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components

That's the first time I am using `Flow` in a work environment, I usually prefer `TypeScript` over `Flow` a lot.

I am having some issue creating a really simple HOC, which is something I did a lot of times with no issues. I am most probably missing something really obvious or something related with Flow that I am not aware of.

I googled a lot but it looks all the posts with the same issues are caused by `default vs named exports/imports`, which does not look my case (I suppose).

Here all the file where I define the HOC (suppose `hoc-sample.js`):

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';

export default function hocSample(Component: any) {
  return class extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>TEST</div>
          <Component />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

As you can see, I export as default a function which returns a component, whose `render` method simply renders the passed component, wrapped inside a `div` with another `div` before.

Here how I import it:

```
import hocSample from 'hoc-sample.js';
```

Here how I create the HOC inside the file:

```
const HOCSample = hocSample(<div>WRAPPED COMPONENT</div>);
```

And here how I use it inside the `render` method:

```
<HOCSample />
```

I get the following error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

Any idea what is the obvious thing that I am missing please?

I double checked in a lot of other projects that I have, and the same code seems to work completely fine.

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847684/how-do-i-pass-an-html-element-to-a-higher-order-function-hoc-in-react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replicated this for you in a codesandbox repo link here https://codesandbox.io/s/x3qr9xqxpz

Your problem is here

```
 const HOCSample = hocSample(<div>WRAPPED COMPONENT</div>);
```

`hocSample` expects a React component not an HTML element, so,

```
const MyApp = () => <div>WRAPPED COMPONENT</div>;
const HOCSample = hocSample(MyApp);
```

Comment: something really obvious was missing :D thanks a lot

Comment: I can understand :D I have been there.

Comment: shame on myself -.-